# SQLiteAssetHelper cant read or write database

Tags: android, sqlite

My app is using `SQLiteAssetHelper` to work with preloaded database.but when i want work with database the app force closes.This is the logcat :

```
   04-15 16:40:48.924  10976-10976/max.mzf.com.max E/SQLiteAssetHelper﹕ Couldn't open myDBName.db for writing (will try read-only):
    com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/myDBName.db.zip file in assets or target folder not writable
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:299)
            at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:273)
            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:376)
            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:355)
            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:178)
            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:257)
            at max.mzf.com.max.MyDatabase.getCardCount(MyDatabase.java:158)
            at max.mzf.com.max.Compose.onCreate(Compose.java:65)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 16:40:48.934  10976-10976/max.mzf.com.max E/AndroidRuntime﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{max.mzf.com.max/max.mzf.com.max.Compose}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2503)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:739)
            at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:267)
            at max.mzf.com.max.MyDatabase.getCardCount(MyDatabase.java:158)
            at max.mzf.com.max.Compose.onCreate(Compose.java:65)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is `SQLiteAssetHelper` class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDBName.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // you can use an alternate constructor to specify a database location
        // (such as a folder on the sd card)
        // you must ensure that this folder is available and you have permission
        // to write to it
        //super(context, DATABASE_NAME, context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath(), null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }
```

And this is part of the activity which reads and writes database:

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Compose extends AppCompatActivity  {


    TextView Count;

    MyDatabase db;
    private Globals globalVariable;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newcard);
        db = new MyDatabase(this);


        Count=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Count);



      Count.setText(String.valueOf(db.getCardCount()));
```

I'm expecting your valuable guides.
BTW,AndroidStudio couldn't resolve `com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper`
so i added it manually into libs folder(i told this, perhaps be needed)

Comment: `Missing databases/myDBName.db.zip file in assets or target folder not writable` -- do you have the packaged database in the spot mentioned in the error message? In terms of Android Studio, [the `SQLiteAssetHelper` documentation has instructions for adding the `compile` statement to your `app/build.gradle` file](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#setup). See also [this sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets-AndroidStudio) that uses `SQLiteAssetHelper`.

Comment: @CommonWare.what do you mean "packaged database"?

Comment: @CommonWare.I have added zipped db to the databases under asset folder.

Comment: Is code breaking on all test devices / phones? If it's breaking only on marshmallow + it's user rights issue

Comment: @ Amod Gokhale_I just tested on API 7 phone it force closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved finally.The sqlAssetHelper lib file was an old version so I replaced with new one.now is working fluently.this is the asset helper which solved the problem: [updated asset helper](http://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=central-proxy&g=com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset&a=sqliteassethelper&v=LATEST&&c=jar)